# Oracle Sizing pl/sql how to get past database size information?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-12c

I am learning Pl\sql developer and just starting to learn about DBA activities. I have been asked to get the sizing information of the past monthly growth of databases and tables. any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you don't have access to AWR due to insane licensing cost, but if you do, that is easily obtainable there. This will help you figure out what you need: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_v_datafile_database_size.htm

Moreover, you can use STATSPACK to track this, it's essentially the manual AWR. Another resource: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:7867887875624

From Burleson Consulting (http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_database_growth_statspack.htm):

> The STATSPACK tables do not have a special table for database growth,
>   but you can query the STATSPACK tables to compute the growth over a
>   specific period of time like this:
>
> - Tracking_oracle_database_tables_growth with STATSPACK
>
> Note that you have to create a STATSPACK extension table, but you can
>   get some great growth reports from STATSPACK data.